# How to display date in a date input field in twig?

Tags: datepicker, twig

my code is as follows:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
<input type="date" name="end" value=" {{ task.end|date('Y-m-d') }} ">
{% endfor %}
```

but no date is displayed in the date-picker.What should I do?

Comment: You should remove the extra spaces you have in the `value` attribute

Comment: @DarkBee post it as an answer ! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra spaces you have in the value attribute

```
<input type="date" name="end" value="{{ task.end|date('Y-m-d') }}">
```